# What is the best way to repeat this loop?

Tags: java

I'm new to this and new to loops. The slot machine code works fine. I want the below code to do the following:
When asked `(Play again? (Y/N?))`, If I respond by saying `Y` the game restarts. If I respond by saying `N`, the program terminates. And finally, if I respond by pressing anything else e.g. `R`, the message repeats `(Play again? (Y/N?))`. I'm thinking a do loop, but not sure what elements go where. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SlotMachine {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int slotOne;
    int slotTwo;
    int slotThree;
    String userResponse;

        Random randomNumbers = new Random();

        slotOne = randomNumbers.nextInt(10);  // Random number between 0 and 9
        slotTwo= randomNumbers.nextInt(10);  
        slotThree = randomNumbers.nextInt(10);  


        System.out.println(slotOne + " " + slotTwo +  " " + slotThree + " " );  // prints all three slot numbers next to each other
        if (slotOne != slotTwo && slotOne != slotThree && slotTwo != slotThree) // ! means does not equal
        { 
            System.out.println("No numbers match");  
        }
        else if (slotOne == slotTwo && slotOne == slotThree) 
        { 
            System.out.println("All three match - jackpot"); 
        } 
        else
        { 
            System.out.println("Two numbers match"); 
        }       

        System.out.print("Play again? (Y/N?)");
        userResponse = scan.next();
```

**UPDATE:**

its the second loop that forces it to close?

Comment: You can use a `switch`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When entering erroneous consecutively, loop breaks java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27899932/when-entering-erroneous-consecutively-loop-breaks-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
userResponse = "Y";
While(userResponse.equals("Y")){
     Random randomNumbers = new Random();
     slotOne = randomNumbers.nextInt(10);  // Random number between 0 and 9
     slotTwo= randomNumbers.nextInt(10);  
     slotThree = randomNumbers.nextInt(10);
     System.out.println(slotOne + " " + slotTwo +  " " + slotThree + " " ); 
     if (slotOne != slotTwo && slotOne != slotThree && slotTwo != slotThree) 
     { 
       System.out.println("No numbers match");  
     }
     else if (slotOne == slotTwo && slotOne == slotThree) 
     { 
       System.out.println("All three match - jackpot"); 
     }else
     { 
            System.out.println("Two numbers match"); 
     }       

     System.out.print("Play again? (Y/N?)");
     userResponse = scan.next();
}
```

Comment: This is good thanks. Is there an option at the end where I could say "Thank You for playing to the user" when userResponse.equals ("N")??

Comment: After the code you can add: if(userResponse.equals("N")){ System.out.println("Thank you for playing to the user") ; }

Comment: And what happens if they input something other than `Y` or `N`?

Comment: You can keep them in a loop until they answer your question with Y or N like this: do{ System.out.print("Play again? (Y/N?)");
     userResponse = scan.next();  }while(!userResponse.equals("Y") && !userResponse.equals("N"))

Comment: Yes, if something else is inputted, the program terminates. I'd like it to repeat the question

Comment: @Adam friendly advice, instead of copying and pasting , try to figure it out by yourself so you can learn something

Comment: @Adam i think my previous response answers that. thanks

Comment: ok. Its working well with one excpetion. This Happens:
9 0 0 
Two numbers match
Play again? (Y/N?)f
Play again? (Y/N?)d
Play again? (Y/N?)e
Play again? (Y/N?)Y
Thank You For Playing

Comment: It obviously should repeat

Answer (score 0):

Use a switch or simple if statements

for example

```
if(input.equals("Y")){
//your code
}  

if(input.equals("N")){
//your code
}  

else{
//your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is often called a "game loop".  Essentially the logic of the whole game is wrapped in a loop which checks for any terminating condition of the game.  In this case, the player saying they don't want to play again.  It might look something like this:

```
boolean playGame = true;
while (playGame) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int slotOne;
    int slotTwo;
    // and so on...

    // then after the game...
    while (!(userResponse.equals("Y") || userResponse.equals("N"))) {
        System.out.print("Play again? (Y/N?)");
        userResponse = scan.next();

        if (userResponse.equals("N")) {
            playGame = false;
        }
    }

}
```

This particular implementation is admittedly a little hurried, but you get the idea.  There's an overall condition which determines if the game is still playable.  If it isn't, the game loop ends.  Internal to that you can also have a user input loop to keep prompting while any invalid input is received.  For simple games you might even combine these two, by declaring `userResponse` outside of the game loop, initializing it to `"Y"`, and doing something like `while (userResponse.Equals("Y"))`.  That semantically couples the two concepts, so for larger games you'd want to separate the loop condition from the user input if for no other reason than cleaner variable names and conditional statements.

You might also find other reasons to break out of a game, in which case you could use something like a `continue` statement to re-iterate the loop part-way through after updating the `playGame` value, to reset or quit the game before it's been completed.

Comment: Get an error message on this one:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at SlotMachine.main(SlotMachine.java:44)

Comment: @Adam: I can't really debug your program for you.  What causes the error?  My Java is *very* rusty, maybe my code needs to do something else with the `Scanner` object?  The overall logic is the same, you might just need to debug and adjust a little for your specific implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with a `switch` statement.

```
switch (userResponse) {
     case "Y":
         //restart game
         break;
     case "N":
         //terminate program
          break;
     default:
         //ask user for input
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets see what is going on

your are right to know that you need a loop

there are 3 of them

> **1**. for loop
>
> **2**. while loop
>
> **3**. do while loop

between all of them you need do while loop

why?

because you want your users go through the process at least once.

lets take a look at the defination of do while loop

**Syntax**:
The syntax of a do...while loop is:

```
do
{
   //Statements
}while(Boolean_expression);
```

> Notice that the Boolean expression appears at the end of the loop, so
>   the statements in the loop execute once before the Boolean is tested.
>
> **If the Boolean expression is true, the flow of control jumps back up
>   to do, and the statements in the loop execute again.** This process
>   repeats until the Boolean expression is false.

For example:

Code:

```
    String answer = "Y";
    do {
        System.out.println("enter number 0 number plz");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());

        System.out.println("would you like to repeate again?");
        answer = sc.next();

    } while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
```

output:

[image]

In the case you want to check whether input is the one you are looking for you can follow this sample

Code:

```
    String answer = "Y";
    do {
        System.out.println("enter number 0 number plz:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
        if (input != 0) {
            System.out.println("your entered number is not zero");
            System.out.println("please try again");

        } else {
            System.out.println("would you like to repeate again?");
            answer = sc.next();
        }

    } while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
```

output:

[image]

Comment: the down voter explanation is appreciated. plz be kind and let me know what I did wrong, thanks

Comment: @PaulRichter what do you mean?

Comment: Well, technically, up votes aren't supposed to be used to "correct" downvotes, according to SO voting regulations. What the hell, its christmas. You're welcome. :p

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66621/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-paul-richter).

Answer (score 0):

A do loop is a reasonable solution. But you'd actually need two loops to do what you're asking. One to check if the response was valid (either 'Y' or 'N') and another to check if the response was 'Y'. So it might look something like this:

```
do {

    ...

    do {
        System.out.print("Play again? (Y/N?)");
        userResponse = scan.next();
    } while (userResponse.equals("Y") || userResponse.equals("N"));
} while (userResponse.equals("Y"));
```